# Store multiple inputs in structure array in C

Tags: c

I am trying to store information in a data structure array using dynamic memory.  I have managed to store one set of information using the codes that I have written, however, I am having problems figuring out how to store the next set of input since my code will only output the last user input.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

struct student {
  int recordCount;
  char *firstName;
};


int i;
char buffer[1000];


int main(){

    struct student *sPtr= (struct student*) malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    sPtr->recordCount = 1;

    while (1){

    sPtr=realloc(sPtr, sizeof(struct student)* sPtr->recordCount);
    sPtr->recordCount++;

    printf("First Name:\n");
    fgets(buffer, 51, stdin);
    if (strncmp(".\n", buffer, 51) == 0) break;

    else{
    sPtr->firstName=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer)));
    strncpy(sPtr->firstName, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    }

 }
```

Right now, if I printf("%s", sPtr->firstName) I would only output the final input from the user, which make sense to me.  My problem is how would I store the input into the struct array. I was thinking of strncpy the input into something like sPtr[counter]->firstName, but I can't seem to get the code to work.  Any help, hints would be greatly appreciated it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `sPtr` is initiated as the header of the student struct array, but while you input more student information, you keep writing to the same header struct, without moving the pointer to the next struct.

My suggestion is, use a separate pointer `newStuPtr`, each time you realloc more space and increase the record count, move the new student pointer forward.

But to make the coding easier, considering using a linked list, or an incremental array.

Also, there may be two mistakes in your codes.

1. `malloc` and `realloc` without `free` will cause memory leaks.
2. For new allocated first name string space, you should account for the additional NULL ending to be added by `strncpy`.

   `sPtr->firstName=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer)));
   strncpy(sPtr->firstName, buffer, strlen(buffer));`

Comment: Hey thank you, I will give that a try.  So should I strcpy sptr->firstName onto the new pointer newStuPtr[x]->firstName? If I use a new pointer, how would the printf look like? e.g. `printf("%s, %s", newStuPtr[1]->firstName, newStuPtr[2]->firstName);` with [ x ] being the struc array in which each data is stored in? This is just a partial program so I didn't include free, there are a few more components to the code.

Comment: `newStuPtr` would be similar to `sPtr`, you can access the i-th struct of the student array either by indexing from the head `sPtr[i]`, or use the `newStuPtr->firstName` and forward it to (i+1)th struct by `newStuPtr += 1`. Please note there's a larger problem that, where do you want to store the names of the students. If the `student` struct is for individual student, then it's unnecessary to store (different) `recordCount` in each one with them. You can resort to C programming book you have for help on the design and data structure, then you'll find much less problems with the codes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the right data structure for your needs. A linked list is a perfect fit for your case:

```
struct student {
  char *firstName;
  student * next;
};
```

Also, calling `realloc` repeatedly is not a good practice. Further usage of `strncpy` over `strcpy` is not encouraged by the most SO users. You are not even copying the `\0` character to mark the string end. Try to use the above data structure and see how things fall in place.

Comment: I don't see how the OP will benefit by using a linked list over an array of structures.

Comment: @RoadRunner, the OP mentions that he wants to use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Whats wrong with dynamically allocating an array of structures though? He even says he wants to "*store information in a data structure array using dynamic memory*".  A linked list does not act as an array.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I cannot use link because the assignment is restricted to dynamic struct array only.